# As a new back-end programmer, is it common to rely on front-end people to handle all CSS?

Tags: php, css, frontend, backend

Been doing a lot of Php & MySQL programming over the past 3 or 4 years.  I really enjoy it, and all its related back-end technology.

I'm mostly doing freelance work here and there, but I am not a design guy, and really don't enjoy tinkering with CSS trying to make it work :)

My question is, is it ok to just be good at the server-side end of things, and outsource / team up with a good CSS person?  How about in the context of things like Wordpress, Drupal, Cake, etc?  Do people expect they're you to setup all their Wordpress functionality, and implement their Photoshop files into designs as well?

I really speaking from a freelance point of view, and not so much working in a major company with tons of programmers / designers.

Comment: depends if your client wants to pay for it or not.  You can just hide it in your cost and find someone reliable to outsource it to.

Answer (score 3):

The very best designers aren't usually the very best developers, or vice-versa. It seems like you would benefit from finding a good partner who excels in design to complement your focus on back-end programming. No need to hide that from those who hire you.

However, even if you're not great with making things look pretty, you should probably be familiar with the code the designers use to make things look pretty. It comes in handy, and you'll at least be able to construct basic designs for prototyping, and eventually reasonably clean, solid designs for final products. And, if a basic change in an existing layout is needed, you won't be afraid to make it yourself. It's a skill set worth building.

Comment: +1, I agree that you should at least be familiar with the code used to construct a design.

Comment: True, and I don't mind making tweaks to existing layouts and such.  But getting a PSD and cutting and up and doing it from scratch is where I am hesitant..

Answer (score 0):

The key for me has been finding a frontend or backend person who has a general enough understanding of the other side works so that you can coordinate enough for him to say

"Ok if we want this element to look like this I need your php function to generate a  with a unique id etc.  My most successful projects have been with developers who specialize in a certain thing but still maintain general knowledge of all the different aspects that go into a project.

Comment: That makes sense.  And I do have CSS knowledge, and "some" experience, however not enough to take the PSDs and create a site.  Tweaks I'm usually ok with though.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, doing "freelance website work" means you end up doing all of the work on your own, but don't get me wrong, building a website these days is extremely easy in most cases and I would suggest you learn CSS if that is what you want to continue doing. Web applications are a different story.

Comment: The tools may be easy enough to grasp, but stellar web design is not something that is "extremely easy," or else we wouldn't have web designers.

Comment: I define a web designer as someone who creates a layout and various things around them in photoshop or what have you. A web developer is someone who puts it all together, css included. Good web design: someone who went to school for graphic design or something similar. Good web developer: Someone who went to school for computer science or something similar. Just look at the big shots like Fantasy Interactive(who know how the web works well), they dont hire web developers to do design, they hire graphic artist. My point being, web development is extremely easy once you know the languages.

Comment: Gotcha, and I agree. "Building a website" to me implied the whole front-end process, design included, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

From a freelance perspective, it depends on how much you're willing to to spend outsourcing to your css/design person. A client is only going to be willing to spend X on the project, it doesn't matter to them how it gets done (or shouldn't). So as long as you don't mind slicing off a percentage of X to pay the designer, that should be fine. Especially if it's not going to be a client you maintain sites for.

Having said that, though, if it's a customer you're going to have to maintain and make changes over time, you're going to really want a background in the design aspect. At least enough to make minimal changes. A complete redesign will probably require outsourcing again.

This is approximately the model I've set up. I'm absolutely horrible with photoshop/graphic creation, but the html + css aspect is not hard.

Answer (score 0):

I had an internship that I mainly did back-end work and the little front-end work was the minutae of moving elements pixel by pixel.  That gave me a strong distaste for front-end work.  But I am in a similar situation as I've primarily been a back-end person and am now transitioning to more front-end work.

My advice would be to get comfortable enough with CSS and the blog/cms frameworks so that you can tweak them and make small modifications.  If a client comes to you and starts saying how they want the front-end to look and you have a blank look on your face or are unable to give a reasonable estimation of how much time it will take to implement the updates (or if it's even possible) that will be a big dissuading factor in their eyes.

Don't be afraid of getting deeper into front-end design as well, it improves your marketability not having to rely on others for a portion of the project.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, heightening you experience in the basics of front-end develop will benefit you for more than one reason. Sometimes the best way to deliver a usable front-end requires specialty programming on the back-end. If you can except what will be happening on the front-end, or even developing the barebones of it yourself, that will help greatly.

You might be asking yourself, "Okay, that doesn't really answer my question?" but in fact it does. It's Web 2.0+ out there... clients expect beautiful, dynamic, and easy-to-use websites. This often requires the use of JavaScript and how it interacts with your server scripts and the CSS, layout, and design of the page.

So, in short, if you're wanting to do freelance stuff, in my opinion, it would be worth your while to expand your horizons. I honestly think the gap between "Web Developer" and "Web Designer" has been slowly closes over the years.

Personally, I work for the computer support department of a state University and all the websites we do are both written and designed by myself without any "outsourcing" of my work. I can do what I need, I can make changes on the fly without waiting for another person to do, and I can test immediately. All three are huge advantages in our environment.

Answer (score 0):

One aspect I wanted to direct your attention to is the choice of your development framework. If your framework supports MVC (model-view-controller) separation, then it's very natural for a developer to work on the M and the C, while the designer (CSS/HTML professional) works on the V component. This creates a great workflow and a good separation of responsibilities - and you can work on two separate files at the same time! They're on HTML peppered with some tags, you're on the logic.

Comment: this is true.  I've found that to be the case with things like CakePhp.  However, something like Wordpress seems so integrated.  But everyone wants Wordpress sites (for some reason)